# declaration of variables in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I am new to C++ I do not understand this type of declaration. For example this is my class:

```
class Complex
{
  public:
    Complex( double r, double i ) : re(r), im(i) {}
    Complex operator+( Complex &other );
    void Display( ) {   cout << re << ", " << im << endl; }

    double re, im;
};
```

I don't understand the declaration in this constructor:

```
Complex( double r, double i ) : re(r), im(i) {}
```

i.e what is the symbol ":" used for and what happen if we declare like this in constructor `re(r), im(i)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a *member initialization list*. It is used to initialize members (believe it or not). In this case, it states that the member `re` should be initialized with `r` and the member `im` should be initialized with `i`.

It is particularly useful for class type members to avoid a potentially expensive unnecessary default initialization at the beginning of the constructor. For example, if you had a `std::string` member, the following constructor would first default construct it to an empty string and then assign to it:

```
Class() { string_member = "Hello"; }
```

Whereas the following constructor would simply construct it with `"Hello"` as an argument to the constructor:

```
Class() : string_member("Hello") { }
```

A `const` member cannot be assigned to after initialization, so must be initialized by the member initialization list (unless you provide an in-class initializer in C++11).